# Easier way to select ith jQuery object of group than $($(".someclass")[i]))?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to cycle through the members of "someclass", not the DOM elements but their jQuery counterparts. I've been using $($(".someclass")[i]), but this is pretty ugly. Is there a more natural way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method:

```
$(".someclass").eq(i);
```

That said, Felix Kling is right: you'd better use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of a loop to iterate over the elements stored in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.each()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) for iterating over the element:

```
$(".someclass").each(function() {
    // use $(this)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**nth-child**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) of jquery.

```
$("ul li:nth-child(1)").addClass("green"); //this select 1 the element  of group
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `each` method to iterate the elements:

```
$(".someclass").each(function(i, e){
  // i is the index
  // e is the element
  // this is the element
  // $(this) is the element wrapped in a jQuery object
  $(this).append("<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>");
});
```

(The parameters in the callback function is optional, as usual.)

Some methods for manipulating elements can take a callback method, so that you can use that to iterate the elements. Example:

```
$(".someclass").append(function(i, h){
  // i is the index
  // h is the current html content
  // Return html to append:
  return "<span>" + (i+1) + "</span>";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$(".someclass:eq("+yourNumberHere+")")
```