# How to select nth element where multiple elements have the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 DIVs on my page each of which have the class 'a'. 
How can I fadeOut just the second element?

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: your code and demo fiddle will fetch you an answer.

Comment: Please edit your title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easier way to select ith jQuery object of group than $($(".someclass")\[i\]))?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706511/easier-way-to-select-ith-jquery-object-of-group-than-someclassi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** selector:

```
$('.a:eq(1)').fadeOut();
```